# Vim indenting multiline var declarations for javascript

Tags: javascript, vim, indentation

I am trying to have vim indent my code like this

```
var foo,
    bar,
    baz;
```

But vim is autoindenting (with =) it like

```
var foo,
bar,
baz;
```

Anyone know how to change this?

Comment: Does this script help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742441/autoindent-for-javascript-in-vim-that-understands-semicolon-insertion

Comment: here my vim does exactly what you want...

Comment: Hmm, I think it might be something that the Janus package does that does this. @Joe It helps on a clean vim run (with no other plugins)

Comment: Does having other plugins enabled change the behavior?

Comment: Yeah, I will have to slowly track down which plugin is causing this, thanks!

Comment: OK, sure thing. If this solves your problem, then we should mark this question as a duplicate.

Comment: The problem was this indenting script https://github.com/pangloss/vim-javascript -- replacing that with the plugin you suggested has fixed the issue, thanks!

Comment: `=` formats text based on the option `equalprg`, you can `:echo &equalprg` and also `:verbose set equalprg` to check what it's set to and where it was set last. Most likely that is the culprit, perhaps coming from some plugin or something.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
vnoremap <Tab> >gv
vnoremap <S-Tab> <gv
```

to your .vimrc , and then just select these lines and push 'Tab' or 'Shift+Tab' for backward